# Morocco for an Indian citizen with an EU resident permit

Tags: indian-citizens, morocco

Can I enter in Morocco for tourism for a week with my italian resident permit?
Do I need a visa before arrival?

Answer (score 3):

According to Timatic, the database used by the airlines, Indian citizens need a visa for Morocco, unless they have a diplomatic or service passport (you'd know if you had one of those.) No exceptions are listed for EU residents who aren't citizens.

Timatic doesn't seem to allow direct linking but you can go to [their website](http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/countryinfo.html), select Country: Morocco, Section: Visa, Subsection: Visa Exemptions and click "Get results".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a visa prior to your visit to Morocco.

Ref: https://morocco.visahq.it/requirements/india/resident-italy/

Comment: Note that Visa HQ isn't an official source.